# Invite Facebook Friends in IOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I want to fetch the facebook friend list & send invitation for my app.

i tried following code:

```
 ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];


    NSLog(@"%@",accounts); `******//I got the null array ***********`
    ACAccount *facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
    NSString *acessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",facebookAccount.credential.oauthToken];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"access_token": acessToken};
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];
    SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest
                              requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                              URL:feedURL
                              parameters:parameters];
    feedRequest.account = facebookAccount;
    [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
     }];
```

Comment: What is your question? It is hard to tell just from a blob of code. Could you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: @Michal, Thanks for your reply! As you see above, i got the accounts array is null. So, i can't get the Facebook friend list & emails for send invitation for the app.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 use the facebook SDK:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

and call:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
}];
```

result should be the data you're looking for.